# Database Backup function not working Properly in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3, database-backups

my normal database size is 32 mb but with this method my database downloaded 97mb and showing error when uploading form localhost/phpmyadmin please tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'file', 'download'));
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'zip'));

    $this->db = $this->load->database($_SESSION["db_name"], TRUE);
    $this->load->model('My_Model');
}
    
 public function backup(){
    
    // Load the DB utility class
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $config = array(
        'format'        => 'zip',
        'filename'      => $_SESSION["db_name"].'_'.time().'.sql'
    );
    
    // Backup your entire database and assign it to a variable
    @$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($config);
    
    write_file('backup/backup_'.date('Y-m-d_H_i_s',time()).'.zip', $backup);

}
```

phpmyadmin Error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Locate the **php.ini** file under your web server  and change following

```
upload_max_filesize=64M
post_max_size=64M
max_execution_time=1000
```